# WCF Routing backup list in client

Tags: wcf, wcf-routing

Is it possible to define a WCF backup list in a client, so that a single-point-of-contact routing service is not nessasary?

I have two services implementing the same contact (interface). If the first service is not avaliable I would like the client to know that the backup service is to be used.

Is this possible or do I have to create a routing service (single-point-of-contact) that the client would communication with?

```
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:49192/OrdinaryCustomerService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomer"
            contract="OrdinaryCustomerServiceReference.ICustomer" name="OrdinaryCustomerService" />
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:49860/PremiumCustomerService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomer"
            contract="PremiumCustomerServiceReference.ICustomer" name="PremiumCustomerService" />
    </client>
    <routing>
        <backupLists>
            <backupList name="CustomerBackupList">
                <add endpointName="PremiumCustomerService"/>
            </backupList>
        </backupLists>
    </routing>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea but i have a similar issue and i have been thinking about creating a routing service on the client (IIS webserver in my case) so that all request on the webserver can fail over to different web services. We also have multiple webservers for fail over so i would put a router on each.

Not ideal but best solution i have found so far.  If the router on the IIS box goes down chances are the IIS will be down as well and therefore our system would have kicked over tot he other webserver anyway.

We also have proper wfc routers with backup for our middle teir but before it was a manual change to the webservice to handle this.